# How to Access a member of a Struct ( accessed via pointer) nested within another Struct (also accessed via pointer)?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, microcontroller

I am having trouble accessing data in a nested Struct. I am trying to realize a SPI-Communication between two MCUs.
The Idea was to provide an easy to manipulate Struct to other functions which is nested in the handler and serialized before transmission.
Accessing the struct during serialization does not work however.

I tried to create a simplified model of my datastructure below.

```
typedef struct a_t{
 uint16_t  member1;        
 uint8_t   member2;
} a_t;

typedef struct b_t
{
 volatile a_t* aPtr;
 volatile uint8_t arrayC[3];
} b_t;

a_t a;
a.member1 = 0xABCD;
a.member2 = 0xEF;

b_t b;
b_t* bPtr = &b;

bPtr->aPtr = &a;
```

To my Understanding, the struct **b** now contains a Pointer to struct **a** while **bPtr** points to struct **b**.
So if i dereference

```
bPtr->aPtr
```

i should get a Pointer to Struct **a**. If i dereference further, I should be able to access the members of **a** like this

```
bPtr->arrayC[0] = (((bPtr->aPtr->member1) >> 8) & 0xFF);
bPtr->arrayC[1] = ((bPtr->aPtr->member1) & 0xFF);
bPtr>arrayC[2] = bPtr->aPtr->member2;
```

Which should lead to **arrayC** containing the following data:

```
bPtr->arrayC[0] == 0xAB;
bPtr->arrayC[1] == 0xCD;
bPtr->arrayC[2] == 0xEF;
```

Sadly i cannot find this is the case with my code. In my Case the Values of **arrayC** are as followed if i try to assign them like shown above

```
bPtr->arrayC[0] == 0x00;
bPtr->arrayC[1] == 0x00;
bPtr->arrayC[2] == 0x00;
```

If I assign Values as followed

```
bPtr->arrayC[0] = 0xAB;
```

The Value changes as intended, so the error must be in the expression

```
(((bPtr->aPtr->member1) >> 8) & 0xFF);
((bPtr->aPtr->member1) & 0xFF);
bPtr->aPtr->member2;
```

I am Sorry if this is a silly question, I could find some double pointer references in other posts. But I did not find an explanation why my solution does not work elsewhere so i am grateful if a more experienced programmer is able to explain my mistake to me.

Edit: I corrected a mistake in the Model in which i wrongly addresed member **bPtr->aPtr** as **b->a**

Edit2: The dereference does work when tested with the following compiler

godbolt.org/z/Wdcahndxh

However the same code produces 0x00 within my MCU (MCU: MKE02Z Processor: Cortex M0+ Compiler: ARM6 C99)

Comment: It seems to work well? Could you please upload the full code? https://godbolt.org/z/cMah84fna

Comment: Sending _pointers_ from one MCU to another has no [valid] meaning. So, (e.g.) in MCU1 (that creates the data) and you send: `write(socket,&b,sizeof(b))` to MCU2, the `aPtr` field that MCU2 gets is _meaningless_. You have to serialize the _data_. I presume that you are attempting to do that with `arrayC`. You must populate `arrayC` on MCU1 and then send the struct to MCU2. Then, MCU2 can _only_ use `arrayC` and _not_ `aPtr` In fact, any struct that you send should _not_ have a pointer in it at all. MCU1 could be 64 bit and MCU2 32 bit and the sizes/offsets will not match up.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. `b->a->member1` should yield a compiler error with the code currently shown in the question, because `struct b_t` has no member named `a`. It should be `b->aPtr->member1`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for taking the time to help me. You are correct, sending a Pointer would be meaningless. The goal here is to serialize a struct into an Array send it via SPI and deserialize it at MCU2. I made a mistake yesterday evening while trying to describe the Problem and wrongly accessed the struct via reference not pointers. I edited that mistake.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are correct. I deeply apologize for coding Garbage. I made a mistake yesterday evening while trying to describe the Problem and wrongly accessed the struct via reference not pointers. I edited that mistake. The way i am trying to access it is: bPtr->aPtr->member1. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @malkaroee Thanks for checking.
I copied the code directly from my project (i left out variables that are not used to emphasize on the logic).
The Compiler you proposed does work however
https://godbolt.org/z/Wdcahndxh

The same code reads out as zero within the Compiler used by me. (No Warning, No Error)
Keil ARM6 Compiler c99.

readMemory[0] = handle->SPI_Packet_tx->packetID; Yields a Zero too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so Sorry. I found my mistake. I switched the order of the arguments for my initialization function and mistakenly put the pointer to the rxBuffer into the txbufferptr of the SPI-handler. The rxBuffer was empty, therefore yielding only 0.

I am Thankful for everyone who took the time to help me.
I am relatively new, should I delete this question? Stackoverflow warns me that i could be blocked from asking if I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sir,

> To my Understanding, the struct b now contains a Pointer to struct a
> while bPtr points to struct b. So if i dereference

Sorry, that is wrong, you must refactor from there, you need to use a structure member to store the address, not the struct name:

```c
// b_t struct has a member named aPtr, by sure you must
// store the address of a here
b.aPtr = &a;
```

Comment: You are correct, the member of b is not a but aPtr. Sadly this was a mistake while asking the question. In my Project I am trying to access like this:

bPtr->aPtr->member1